# Visual studio code and ODBC JDBC

Tags: visual-studio-code, jdbc, odbc

Is there any workaround to have ODBC or JDBC connection in visual studio code?
I can't find a way to explore a database using a ODBC or JDBC connection from this IDE.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your time.